# Main display changes after remote desktop connection

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

My office/dev PC is a triple monitor machine running Windows 2008R2. I occasionally remote desktop to this machine from home, using a single monitor. After I do that, the "Main Display" reverts to the leftmost of the three monitors, and I need to reconfigure my monitor settings when I get back to the office.

I do have DisplayFusion installed for menu bars on all screens, and haven't tried to disable that to see if that's the culprit.

But I have switched the video ports driving the leftmost and center monitor, thinking that maybe my machine was just reverting to a default video out as the main display. That didn't help.

Anyone else seen this? Any ideas on how to get the "Main display" to stay set to my center monitor?

Comment: I think this is a bug that was fixed in a QFE package or maybe in 2012(R2). I can't confirm, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the key to this was that the confgi is also lost during a restart, which let me find the hotfix at Microsoft that fixes this.

All is good after installing the hotfix referenced at:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2496400